# OSX: Permissions issue after installing Ruby Gem or Node modules

Tags: ruby, node.js, macos, terminal

I've recently started having an issue installing any Ruby gem or node modules on my local dev environment when it comes to installing anything via the terminal. It was working normally for some time.

```
sudo gem install compass
```

This appears to install correctly however when i run

```
compass -v
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/compass: Permission denied
```

When I browse to /usr/bin/compass and "Get Info" on compass it says system - Read & Write, everyone - No Access as opposed to everyone - read only or...

```
-rwx------   1 root   wheel       512 Jul 27 14:46 compass
```

For some reason everything is getting written with incorrect permissions.

Same goes for Node.js modules.

```
sudo npm install gulp
```

Appears to work but I get the same permissions issue when I try to use it

```
/usr/local/bin/gulp: Permission denied
```

I've exhausted my search and hope someone can help provide some insight on how I can permanently fix this issue

Comment: Might be a red herring, but have you tried Disk Doctor's [Repair Permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201560) feature? If you're using Homebrew, does `brew doctor` show any problems?

Comment: You're on OS X. Using `sudo` means you're modifying the Apple-installed Ruby, which isn't what you want to do. That you're getting permission errors for what should be executables in /usr/local/bin is a bad sign, but without more information about your environment we're guessing. I'd *strongly* suggest you STOP using `sudo` to install, and switch to using [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). Read what they do and their differences, and STOP using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're installing gems with sudo and, as such, root is taking possession of everything. So, instead of using sudo I'd advise using [RVM](https://rvm.io/). RVM provides you with an easy way to manage multiple versions of Ruby, each of which gets their own home for gems in `~/.rvm` which avoids the permission difficulties you're experiencing. Additionally, it's possible (but not recommended) to do a global RVM install that works for all users.

EDIT: As the Tin Man mentioned in response to me, a global RVM install is not only not recommended in a general sense, but the RVM authors themselves advise against it. Caveat emptor and such. You should find the single-user version more than adequate in any case, though.

Comment: Note: A global install is not recommended by the RVM authors. That's significant.